# GET Request works in postman but timeout in curl command

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch, terminal, postman

I am using elasticsearch cloud free trail.
Get request with basic Authorization works in POSTMAN but not works in terminal curl or in PHP.

Here is screenshot of POSTMAN
[image]

Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Max-Age →1728000
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →262
Content-Type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date →Fri, 17 Feb 2017 06:43:12 GMT
Server →fp/0d3c07
X-Found-Handling-Cluster →3aa4393cee54e06b397099c2cb89c0ea
X-Found-Handling-Instance →instance-0000000000
X-Found-Handling-Server →10.67.187.222
```

I am running command as follows

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpOa3BQaDJ3NTlRWVJKa2ZIeWRRQmRXeHc=" "https://3aa4393cee54e06b397099c2cb89c0ea.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243/"
```

Comment: I just tried your curl command and it works perfectly well and I got the answer

Comment: Also note that you should note post your credentials for everyone to see. Even if you only have 6 small indices ;-)

Comment: @Val :-) its testing server

Comment: @Val curl command not working at my end any suggestion

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking outbound traffic ?

Comment: No, it works in POSTMAN

Comment: @Val thanks for hint, i got solution here https://gist.github.com/joridos/673aa658e46a7342b154

Comment: You should have mentioned that you were getting a "Network unreachable" error

Comment: @NileshYadav - Did you resolve this? I am having the same issue but im getting time out error when making a post request yet it works fine in postman but not in curl either via php or via the command line.

Comment: @Birdy Check if your port 443 may block or you can try this https://gist.github.com/joridos/673aa658e46a7342b154

Comment: I have the same issue